# How to rebind methods that have the same name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Having coded a reusable chart in [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) I want to expose the `.tickFormat()` method of both the X-axis **AND** Y-axis. The problem is that they both have the same method name, so my histogram object can only call the most recently added `.tickFormat()` method.

```
d3.ninja.histogram = function module() {
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal(),
        y = d3.scale.linear(),
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom').tickSize(6, 0),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').tickSize(6, 0);

    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function (data) {

            // make something nice

        });
    }

    // Expose the x-axis' tickFormat method.
    d3.rebind(chart, xAxis, 'tickFormat');

    // Expose the y-axis' tickFormat method.
    d3.rebind(chart, yAxis, 'tickFormat');

    return chart;
}
```

Mike Bostock [mentions that](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals)

> The rebind operator allows inherited methods (mix-ins) to be rebound to a subclass on a different object.

I don't really understand how to do this, but wonder if it is a way to tackle my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebind doesn't seem appropriate in this case since it seems likely that you'll want to set tick format separately for each axis. Thus it's not a 1-to-1 pass through scenario.

Exposing them as separate properties and manually calling the underlying axis function is probably what you want:

```
chart.yTickFormat = function(tickFormat) {
     yAxis.tickFormat(tickFormat);
     return chart;
};

chart.xTickFormat = function(tickFormat) {
     xAxis.tickFormat(tickFormat);
     return chart;
};

return chart;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually what I was doing but I felt like I was having to manage too much code and hoped there was a neater way to do it. It seems like there isn't, so I'll mark this as Answered. Thanks :)